# Using external source folders

Tags: android, build, codenameone

I have my codenameone project configured with a linked external source
folder.  The java sources in the external folder are not being included
in android builds.  How to fix this to include the external sources.

It works fine in the simulator environment.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to add an additional src line to the build.xml

```
            <javac destdir="build/tmp" compiler="modern"
            source="1.5"
            target="1.5"
            bootclasspath="lib/CLDC11.jar"
            classpath="lib/CodenameOne.jar:${build.classes.dir}:lib/impl/cls">
            <src path="src"/>
            <src path="../whereever/src"/>
        </javac>
```

Comment: There are more than one place to do this in the build XML if I recall correctly (might be wrong here).